# Setters not working

Tags: java

```
public class Shape{

    public int xPos = 10;
    public int yPos = 20;

    Shape(){

    }

    public int getXpos(){
        return xPos;
    }

    public void setXpos(int x){
        this.xPos = x;
    }

    public int getYpos(){
        return yPos;
    }

    public void setYpos(int y){
        this.yPos = y;
    }

}

public class Shape1 extends Shape{

    Shape1(){
        xPos = 100;
        yPos = 200;
    }

}

public class Test{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Shape1 shape1 = new Shape1();

        System.out.println(shape1.getXpos());
    }

}
```

Why am I getting 10 as a result instead 100?

Comment: This is not even valid Java. Show us the *actual* code you're running.

Comment: I's it a homework task? It seems like it. Should be marked as one.

Comment: No, I'm just making my own program.

Comment: Are you sure that's all your code?

Comment: Actually I can't reproduce, it is working fine for me, outputting 100.

Comment: For me too... it's giving 100 on the console

Comment: Anonymous181, I suggest you try again to run your code. Since the code you post was not directly compilable, maybe you are using something different that cause the problem

Comment: BTW, just so it's said...if you must provide access to a field (which is a bit ugly in itself, but useful for data objects), provide a getter/setter *xor* a public field.  Not both.  Ever.  *Period.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Now my question is: Why am I getting 10 as a result instead 100?

The code as presented prints out 100. The most likely explanation is that you're not running the code that you say you're running. This could happen due to copy-and-paste errors, deployment problems etc.

One little-known but nasty way in which your code could be subtly modified to print `10` is by adding `void` in front of the `Shape1`'s constructor:

```
void Shape1() {
    xPos = 100;
    yPos = 200;
}
```

This transforms `Shape1()` from a constructor into a normal method (which doesn't automatically get called during object construction).

My compiler accepts this modification, and the code prints out `10` when I run it.

I actually once had to deal with a real bug caused by this. Took a little while to spot, I can tell you.

Comment: void Shape1() - why do u change the constructor to method? do public Shape1() instead void Shape1().

Comment: @Quoi: Did you actually read the answer?  His whole point is that the code, as it was written, is correct...but that that slight change would cause it to break in the way the question describes.  Meaning something pretty much the same as that is probably what is wrong with the original (pre-question) code in the first place.

Comment: dude ans is fine i am agree with it what is described(+1). But question was **Why am I getting 10 as a result instead 100?** probably he/she wants the explanation, i think/

Comment: @Quoi: And the explanation is right there in the answer.  If the constructor is accidentally turned into a method (by sticking `void` in front of it, for example), it won't get called during construction -- so the fields won't get changed from what the base class set them to.